# Pointer and pointer variable

Tags: c

I want to know  the difference between these two statements.

```
int *X,a;
X=&a;
```

I understand that X will point towards address of a. Instead of that if I only use

```
int *X;
```

So, if X is a pointer variable, can I use it to assign values, instead of using other variable a?

Comment: First you need to allocate memory to `X` then you can use it to store values.

Comment: In the first case, `X` points to a valid memory whereas in the latter, `X` is uninitialized. They are not equivalent and hence you answer to your question is *no* until you initialize `X`.

Comment: Ok, I can allocate memory.But, I want to know the difference. By that, I mean what will be the benefit of using a pointer variable directly to assign values, instead of using it as a indicator to other variable ?

Comment: `X` does not point to the address of a`. Rather, `X` points to `a`, and the value of `X` is the address of `a`.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, what is unclear about this question ?

Comment: For me, this isn't enough for a downvote, but one could argue that this question lacks research effort (if knowing the basics about a language is considered as such) or is not useful (I don't expect this question to help people in the future).

Comment: And addressing the question (I don't think it's important enough to make it an answer), you can do things like `char *foo = (char *)0x1234`, which is useless in portable code, but often used in embedded systems to access memory-mapped devices etc.

Comment: Ok. But,everyone here is not a born programmer. I am a Mechanical engineer and I need to learn it for simulations. Probably this is not the right place to post basic doubts.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a normal variable such as `int a;` you allocate memory where *values* can be stored. But when you declare a pointer, `int* x;` you allocate memory where an *address* can be stored.

So when you type `int* x = &a;` you store the address of `a` in the pointer `x`. After that, you can change the contents of a by writing `*x = something;` because you access the contents of the address where that pointer is pointing at.

If you just declare a pointer `int* x;` and not set it to point anywhere, it will contain a garbage address, which does not point at valid memory. So if you use it `*x = something;` without setting it to point at a valid address first, the program will attempt to write to a random garbage address, which is a bug - the program will likely crash.

Pointers are not any different from plain variables here. Should you write code like `int a; printf("%d",a);` the program will print garbage and possibly crash, because you didn't initialize the variable to something valid.

Comment: In the context of the OP -- where `a`'s address is taken -- `int a; printf("%d",a);` is perfectly correct (a cannot have register storage class). Btw, do you know of a system which indeed traps when `a`'s adddress is not taken?

Comment: @PeterSchneider In theory, `a` could be a trap representation, because the value is indeterminate, which is defined by C **3.19.2
indeterminate value** `"either an unspecified value or a trap representation"`. So it is UB. In practice, I have never encountered a system that will trap for that though.

Comment: `int`s as such do obviously not have trap representations (all bit patterns are valid ints). On some architectures though, int *registers* may carry an "uninitialized" flag *in addition* to the value bits, but that comes only into play for variables who can have register storage class, which in turn can only be those whose address is never taken.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Formally, they can have trap representation and padding bits. See 6.2.6.2. For example, a system using one's complement could trap on negative zero. This is regardless of storage class. In reality I have never encountered such obscure implementations though.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Short answer: Treat reading of uninitialized values as UB. The standards differ slightly here (C89 made reading such a value UB explicitly), but e.g. Gcc and Clang (for all standards) always considered it UB and reorder statements and allocate registers for variables based on the assumption that no read of a value occurs before the first write.

Comment: An int with padding bits! Interesting. -- Itanium apparently has a "not a thing" flag in registers which could trap (as discussed in the defect report (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm). But I'm a bit puzzled. 6.3.2.1,2 says clearly that UB occurs [only, I read it] if "the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken)". But I understand that some architectures can have ints (and surely floats) in memory which are trap representations. Does reading one not trap?

Comment: @mafso yes, I have read the discussions e.g. with respect to using unintialized variables for more entropy which kindof backfired because the compiler decides that nothing has to be done with an uninitialized value.

Comment: @PeterSchneider The Annex J (not normative) of the standard list the following as UB: "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)." In 6.2.4 they state the rules for scopes and when a variable's value becomes indeterminate. 6.7.9 then states "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate." Nowhere is it mentioned what will happen when you access an indeterminate value: it is outside the scope of the standard and thus UB.

Comment: And of course if the variable contains a trap representation and you access it, the standard explicitly says it is UB, see 6.2.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

A value of a pointer is an address of an object. If you have a pointer to int (`int*`), its value is an address of an `int` object. The `int` object's value is a integer number.

An uninitialized int* variable (declared with `int *x;`) has a "garbage" (undefined) value, so it points to an unknown "something". Running this code:

```
int* x;
*x = 5;
```

will probably result in a segfault because you try to write an int value to an address that is not valid. It's an undefined behavior to do that.

To make a pointer point to a valid piece of memory, you need to either set it to an otherwise initialized memory (as in you first snippet) or allocate the memory with malloc (or equivalent);

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = 5;
```

Now `x` points to a valid piece of RAM that can hold an int value.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a pointer, memory is allocated on the stack to store the address of the actual data (in this case an `int`). Until you assign an address to the pointer, there is no actual `int` that it is referencing and therefore dereferencing produces undefined behavior. If you don't want to assign it the address of a different variable, you will have to create memory for the `int` on the heap:

```
int *X;
X = malloc( sizeof *X );
```

Then when you are done, be sure to release the memory:

```
free( x );
```

Comment: There is however no obligation to create memory on the heap just because you have an uninitialized pointer. The memory pointed at could be allocated anywhere, the pointer itself doesn't care :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    int N =2;

    int *X = malloc ( N * sizeof * X );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        X[ i ] = i;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        printf("\nX[%d] = %d\n", X[ i ] );

    free ( X );

return 0;


}
```

Where you can see that in the first loop you are assigning values to X.
But in order to do so , you have first to malloc the appropriate size of X.

Comment: Casting the result of malloc is pointless and potentially dangerous. Read the SO frequent questions below the C tag.

Comment: Opinions differ on casting, as you can see in the debate @Lundin pointed you to. I'm one of the 10 percent or so who do like to cast, partly because C code tends to migrate to C++ and it's good to be ready for it. I also like the stronger type checking of C++ which was introduced for a reason. That later versions of C do not check stricter has only to do with the amount of legacy code out there which would stop compiling because it does overly lenient implicit legacy conversions, like void* to int*.

Comment: @Peter Schneider:Ok, thank you very much for the information.I already checked the link.

Comment: @PeterSchneider The people who argue in favour of the cast tend to be C++ programmers who have yet to discover static analysers... And I'm not quite sure why professional C programmers should heed the advice of hobbyist C++ programmers.

Comment: @Lundin The C++ programmers *have* discovered at least one static analyzer. It's called "C++ compiler". And the C rogrammers should heed the advice (hobby or not) solely based on reasoning of wich I provided some, directly and indirectly. Of course everybody must make up their own mind based on the arguments on both sides; and it's probably not the most important debate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you define a pointer, you can use it to store pointers to a memory location.
If you want to store a value in a specific memory location pointed by a pointer, you need to allocate a memory area to store the value, in your example you can use `X` to store values with something like:

```
int *X;

X=(int*)calloc(1,sizeof(int));

// Storing a value into the memory location pointed by X
*X=10;

// ... stuff...
// When you're done using X:
free(X);
```

Comment: Casting the result of malloc is pointless and potentially dangerous. Read the SO frequent questions below the C tag.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is meant to hold the address of an object. Sometimes a variable like `a` is used to access such an object, sometimes not (e.g. if you have an array element or allocate on the free store).

Once you have the pointer pointing to an object -- invariably after you assigned the address of one to the pointer -- you can change that object's contents through the pointer.

If you never assigned a value to the pointer (or initialized it, which technically differs ever-so-slightly from assignment), the pointer will contain either the invalid address null or an arbitrary address which will only coincidentally be a valid address, and any attempt to access that memory will likely fail, silently or not.